# Project management app for web developers?

Tags: drupal, project-management, whmcs

I am tired of having to manage projects manually. We use subversion for version control, but ultimately, I want an app that can:

- Send out notifications to clients on the progress of their projects
- Allow clients to log in and see screenshots of projects
- Keep track of money paid, as well as invoice due dates and how much is outstanding
- Allow clients to post any queries regarding the project in an area
- Manage several projects

I currently use

- SubVersion
- WHMCS --> would be great if it could integrate into this

Any suggestions would be great? Or might I have to write an app like this myself?

Comment: i ended up writing my own project management tool. I'll make it publicly available for free, if it turns out to be very useful. so far it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Redmine
>
> Redmine is a flexible project
>   management web application. Written
>   using Ruby on Rails framework, it is
>   cross-platform and cross-database.
>
> Redmine is open source and released
>   under the terms of the GNU General
>   Public License v2 (GPL). Features
>
> Below are some of the main features of
>   Redmine.
>
> ```
> Multiple projects support
> Flexible role based access control
> Flexible issue tracking system
> Gantt chart and calendar
> News, documents & files management
> Feeds & email notifications
> Per project wiki
> Per project forums
> Time tracking
> Custom fields for issues, time-entries, projects and users
> SCM integration (SVN, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Bazaar and Darcs)
> Issue creation via email
> Multiple LDAP authentication support
> User self-registration support
> Multilanguage support
> Multiple databases support
> ```

[Go Redmine site](http://www.redmine.org/)

Comment: Seems like you beat me to recomending this :)

Comment: Also I want to recommending 'Timesheet' module for userful developers time management.

Comment: Still playing with Redmine. Not entirely sure if it will prove beneficial yet.

Comment: Remember to look into the plugins as well. It might be that some of them will cover what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You should definately check out [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com). This has loads of awesome features and can do all of the above (plus a whole lot more). Also, we'll be bringing out some great new functionality on the finance side in the next few weeks.

Dave

Comment: Will check it out and report back. :-)

Comment: Waaaaaaaay too pricey for a 2 person IT company. If it was 15 USD per month, I'd pay it.

Comment: HI RD - It's free for 3 Users, so for a 2 person co it would work well. There is the limitation that it cannot be public facing for free version (only for internal use) so a 5 user license would be required to expose it to your clients.

Comment: Can it still send notifications to them (the clients)?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at Redmine: http://www.redmine.org/
As of now, I've only been looking at it for my 2 person company, and as it integrages subversion and other version control system directly into projects, I think it's an OK choise.

But as mentioned, I haven't used it in production like environemts yet, but it look well tested.
There is also a Turnkey version of it, which is ready to be used as a live CD or in a Virtual Machine: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine

/Kristoffer

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something that is hosted I would consider assembla.com. It has just about every feature you could want, and has worked really well for me in the past.

http://www.assembla.com/

Answer (score 0):

We use [PivotalTracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com/)

Doesn't have all the features you mention, but it is useful for client interaction and project management.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the app yourself, but you'd likely be better off just going with a SaaS! Believe it.

Your software needs are a bit ahead of what traditional project management apps offer, and it is likely you'll find many systems to be insufficient.

*Warning:* Just because most PM apps will be insufficient doesn't mean you should settle with multiple different apps. This will lead to double entry, inefficiency, and a list of other problems that come with apps that don't integrate properly. You're better off with something that combines everything you need into one system.

You could try WORKetc, they have a 14 day free trial and combine all the core essentials for web devs. CRM, Project management, collaboration tools, billing, support tools, email marketing, and even client logins (invite clients/contractors to check on projects you're working on related to them + they can collaborate).

WORKetc combines key tools so that it can be used to manage an entire small business. Combined alerts, reminders, calendars, to-dos, document sharing, and a bunch of other features. Worth looking into, other than that I'd recommend looking at the Google Apps Marketplace. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the size and scope of your projects.

I would say that JIRA is the best system available at the moment and if you only require a small number of users (<=10) then it is only $10 a month.

It's definitely the most complete system out there but obviously there is the hurdle of cost and getting it set up (there is a lot of initial set up to get workflows and things working how you like them).