# Simple program to keep clients in the loop?

Tags: drupal, project-management, redmine, whmcs

This is a follow up to this question: [Project management app for web developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548521/project-management-app-for-web-developers/5550270#comment-6327678)

Basically, redmine is a bit overkill. I just want to be able to:

1. Split a project into X sized chunks
2. Notify clients when sections are completed
3. Allow clients to log in at any point and see the progress of their project

Maybe there are plugins that can provide this functionality?

It would be great if this app could source the clients from WHMCS. And I really would hate to have to do this myself from scratch. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Project management app for web developers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548521/project-management-app-for-web-developers)

Comment: You might want to consider responding to and updating the original question rather than creating a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Basecamp? http://basecamphq.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try be our(Drupal) own [OpenAtrium](http://openatrium.com/)